# Angularjs add validation to dynamic fields using $compile

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, compilation

Am trying to add required to an input element in my form.
However, the form is dynamic.If I put the element manually in the page it works,but if i use the $compile it doesn't work.

My Html:

```
<div style="padding-left:20px; padding-right:20px">
<ng-form name="Myform">

                <div id="appendHere"></div>


                <button   type="submit" ng-disabled="Myform.$invalid"  class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>

            </div>

    </div>
</ng-form></div>
```

My Controlles js:

```
'use strict';

myapp.controller("CompileController", ["$scope", "$compile", 
    function ($scope, $compile) {
 var $result = $("<ng-form name='form'><div class='form-group'><h5><label class='col-xs-2 col-form-label'>Absence Status</label></h5><div class='col-xs-10'><input class='form-control' required  name='AbsenceStatus' type='text' ng-model='requestL.AbsenceStatus'/></div></div></ng-form>").appendTo(angular.element("#appendHere"));


        $compile($result)($scope);

  }]);
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. I am using angularjs 1.5.8.

Thx,

Comment: Can you try var $results=$("#appendHere").append("<ng-form name='form'><div class='form-group'><h5><label class='col-xs-2 col-form-label'>Absence Status</label></h5><div class='col-xs-10'><input class='form-control' required  name='AbsenceStatus' type='text' ng-model='requestL.AbsenceStatus'/></div></div></ng-form>");
$compile($result)($scope);

Comment: @kernallora same issue

Answer (score 0):

you can try the following code in controller. it worked for me. 
One possible solution is to put it into a 0 second $timeout-function

```
var $result = "<ng-form name='form'><div class='form-group'><h5><label class='col-xs-2 col-form-label'>Absence Status</label></h5><div class='col-xs-10'><input class='form-control' required  name='AbsenceStatus' type='text' ng-model='requestL.AbsenceStatus'/></div></div></ng-form>";
var content = $compile($result)($scope);
console.log(content);
$timeout(function(){
      var tempElement = document.createElement('div');
      tempElement.innerHTML = content[0].innerHTML;     
      document.getElementById('appendHere').appendChild(tempElement.firstChild);
    });
```

here is example in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cLenjedL/4/) as well.